# Call WebMethod from another project using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I created a project in Visual Studio named '**MyProject**', and Added .aspx file to it named '**MyPage.aspx**'.

In '**MyPage.aspx.cs**', there is a web method as shown below

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
        public static string GetDetails()
        {
            try
            {
                var data= HttpContext.Current.Session["mySession"] as myDto;
                return myDto.Username;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Sorry";
            }
        }
```

Now, I created another project in that same solution named '**NewProject**'.
And I have a page in this project as '**NewPage.aspx**', from which I am trying to call GetDetails() from '**MyPage.aspx**' (MyProject).

So I tried the following code.

**NewPage.aspx**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: 'http://localhost:2463/MyPage.aspx/GetDetails',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                                alert('Error');
                            }
            })

        });
    </script>
```

but the Web Method isn't getting hit & I get the 'Error' alert displayed.

I also tried this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost:2463/MyPage.aspx/GetDetails",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: '{}',
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert('success');
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    });
    });

</script>
```

but no luck.

Plz Help...!!

Comment: check the details of `response` in the error

Comment: why cant you use a webservice?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a CORS problem.

By default you cant access a service that is not within the origin domain (scheme, hostname, port).

Comment: for .net 4.5 you can use cors library to activate cross-domain requests (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx). Using json as response should help maybe too  (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667387/Jquery-Cross-Domain-ajax-call-using-JSONP). Another probably useful link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43038/Accessing-Remote-ASP-NET-Web-Services-Using-JSONP)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that link http://localhost:2463/MyPage.aspx/GetDetails is available while making jquery ajax call. For that 
you can run MyProject in a seperate instance of VS and then run NewProject in another instance of VS.

Answer (score 0):

Check console in inspect element and find a solution for given error.
You can call webMethod of another page. Your code seems correct.
And no need to write whole URL ('http://localhost:2463/MyPage.aspx/GetDetails') of a page, Just write  'MyPage.aspx/GetDetails'.